# AttributeError: module 'matplotlib.pyplot' has no attribute 'pyplot'

Tags: python, matplotlib, visual-studio-code, anaconda, attributeerror

Solved it while writing this question, leaving it up for any further idiot like me having trouble.

I've recently started to write in python through  some tutorials, and cannot utilize matplotlib.

Setup:

- VS Code, **no virtual environment**
- Anaconda 3 (so as far as I know, matplotlib should work)

Error:

I get the following error when running my code:

```
> PS C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Python Course> python Testing.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Testing.py", line 66, in <module>
    plt.pyplot.hist(dataset["horsepower"])
AttributeError: module 'matplotlib.pyplot' has no attribute 'pyplot'
```

Measures:

- I've tried importing pyplot as `from matplotlib import pyplot as plt` and as `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`, also tried importing `matplotlib` first, then importing `pyplot` to no effect.
- `pip install --upgrade matplotlib` (already had it installed, but did it just to make sure)
- after "upgrading" matplotlib, could'nt check matplotlib version with `matplotlib.__version__`, so I entered `pip list` and there I found `matplotlib 3.2.1` making me believe it's not an installation error?
- I finally created a .pth file in `D:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages` called `example.pth` containing **only** the following:

> C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\Scripts

I've gone through all the similarly asked questions for this issue and cannot figure it out. So much so I finally created a SO account for this.

Example Code:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

#importing dataset csv
path = "C:\\Users\\USER\\Desktop\\Python Course\\vehicle.data"
dataset=pd.read_csv(path, header=None)

#assigning non-existant headers
headers = ["symboling","normalized-losses","make","fuel-type","aspiration", "num-of-doors","body-style",
         "drive-wheels","engine-location","wheel-base", "length","width","height","curb-weight","engine-type",
         "num-of-cylinders", "engine-size","fuel-system","bore","stroke","compression-ratio","horsepower",
         "peak-rpm","city-mpg","highway-mpg","price"]
dataset.columns = headers

#eliminates cars with no price recording
dataset.dropna(subset=["price"], axis=0)

dataset[['length','compression-ratio'] ].describe()

#converting to km
dataset["city-mpg"]=235/dataset["city-mpg"]
dataset.rename(columns={"city-mpg": "city-L/100Km"}, inplace=True)
dataset["highway-mpg"]=235/dataset["highway-mpg"]
dataset.rename(columns={"highway-mpg": "highway-L/100Km"}, inplace=True)

#standarizing missing values to NaN (python default)
dataset.replace("?", np.nan, inplace = True)
missing_data = dataset.isnull() #(False=not missing value, true=missing value)


#Replacing normalized-loss
avg_normloss=dataset["normalized-losses"].astype("float").mean(axis=0) #122.0
dataset["normalized-losses"].replace(np.nan, avg_normloss, inplace=True)
#stroke
avg_stroke=dataset["stroke"].astype("float").mean(axis=0) #122.0
dataset["stroke"].replace(np.nan, avg_stroke, inplace=True)
#bore
avg_bore=dataset["bore"].astype("float").mean(axis=0) #122.0
dataset["bore"].replace(np.nan, avg_bore, inplace=True)
#horsepower
avg_HP=dataset["horsepower"].astype("float").mean(axis=0) #122.0
dataset["horsepower"].replace(np.nan, avg_HP, inplace=True)
#peak-rpm
avg_peak=dataset["peak-rpm"].astype("float").mean(axis=0) #122.0
dataset["peak-rpm"].replace(np.nan, avg_peak, inplace=True)
#num-of-doors
freq_doors=dataset['num-of-doors'].value_counts().idxmax()
dataset["num-of-doors"].replace(np.nan, freq_doors, inplace=True)
#Dropping rows with no price
dataset.dropna(subset=["price"],axis=0,inplace=True)
#reset index
dataset.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

#data types corrections
dataset[["bore", "stroke", "price", "peak-rpm"]] = dataset[["bore", "stroke", "price", "peak-rpm"]].astype("float")
dataset[["normalized-losses", "horsepower"]] = dataset[["normalized-losses", "horsepower"]].astype("int")

#normalization
#0 to 1 values
dataset['length'] = dataset['length']/dataset['length'].max()
dataset['width'] = dataset['width']/dataset['width'].max()
dataset['height'] = dataset['height']/dataset['height'].max()

#HP histrogram
plt.pyplot.hist(dataset["horsepower"])
plt.pyplot.xlabel("horsepower")
plt.pyplot.ylabel("count")
plt.pyplot.title("horsepower bins")

bins = np.linspace(min(dataset["horsepower"]), max(dataset["horsepower"]), 4)
group_names = ['Low', 'Medium', 'High']
dataset.to_csv("vehicledata.csv", index=False)
```

The referenced file in the code is found here: [File](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/autos/imports-85.data%22%20target=%22_blank%22%3Ehttps://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/autos/imports-85.data)

**SOLVED**
`plt.pyplot.hist(dataset["horsepower"])` and the 3 subsequent lines of code were wrong. Writing `plt.pyplot.hist()` was redundant, and in my case non-obviously wrong. Changing the call to `plt.hist()` fixed my issues.

Comment: Why not use a Conda environment, if you already have Anaconda installed?

Comment: As far as I know (which isn't much) I do use a Conda environment, as I run it with VS Code and when it launches it launches with -Conda something. Or are you referring to something else?